# How to get a max of a measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the below data:

[image]

(last column shall be a sum grouped by **BU** and **UP**).

I have achieved the last column **SubTotalBU**, by doing:

```
SubTotalBU = CALCULATE ( sum(Sheet1[NSR]), ALLSELECTED(), VALUES(Sheet1[BU]),  VALUES(Sheet1[UP]) )
```

My goal is to get the **max** of column **SubTotalBU** for each **UP**… That is; I need a column  with all values 90 in this case.

I have tried using MAX of SubTotalBU, but MAX doesn’t work with measures… How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

To display all max total in your table report, you need to create a new column for the value, else the table will auto filter the value base on the table row:

**First**, create new column for `Total BU`:

```
Tottal BU = CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[NSR]),FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Bu] = EARLIER(Sheet1[Bu])))
```

**Next**, create a new column to record only `max value` from the `Total BU`

```
Max BU = MAX(Sheet1[Tottal BU])
```

**Sample data with new column:**

[image]

**Table Report:**

[image]